# Sqlite - best way to insert a row with a new unique value in a column that is not unique?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to do the following in sqlite.

For certain application tasks (basically creation), insert a row into a table and assign its id column a new unique value.

However for other application tasks (basically annotation or update tasks), it may assign a row to the same table with an existing id column value.  This precludes using a autincrement primary key.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A way could be to mimic the generation of the rowid column but not limit it to being UNIQUE.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thetable (id INTEGER, other TEXT);
/* add with unique id */
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES((SELECT coalesce(max(id),0) + 1 FROM thetable),'blah1');
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES((SELECT coalesce(max(id),0) + 1 FROM thetable),'blah2');
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES((SELECT coalesce(max(id),0) + 1 FROM thetable),'blah3');
/* add with any value existing or not */
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(2,'blahx');
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(2,'blahy');
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(2000,'blahz');
/* and another unique */
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES((SELECT coalesce(max(id),0) + 1 FROM thetable),'blah9999');
SELECT rowid AS therealid,* FROM thetable;
```

This results in :-

[image]

The **therealid** uses the normally hidden **rowid** column which always exists unless the table has been defined with the WITHOUT ROWID clause.

Another way that would be more efficient BUT may not always produce a unique value could be to use the random() function to generate a random value between between -9223372036854775808 and +9223372036854775807 e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anothertable (id INTEGER DEFAULT (random()), other TEXT);
INSERT INTO anothertable (other) VALUES('blah1'),('blah2'),('blah3');
INSERT INTO anothertable VALUES(2,'blahx');
INSERT INTO anothertable VALUES(2,'blahy');
INSERT INTO anothertable VALUES(2000,'blahz');
INSERT INTO anothertable (other) VALUES('blah9999');
SELECT rowid AS therealid,* FROM anothertable;
```

This results in (values are not consistent) :-

[image]